# How to independently randomize three numbers from $[0, 1]$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

My goal is to randomize $U_1, U_2, U_3 \sim U[0, 1]$ independently such that $U_1 + U_2 + U_3 = 1$.

I'm not sure how to do it. My first idea was to choose $U_1 \sim[0, 1]$, then randomize $U_2 \sim U[U_1, 1]$ and then $U_3 = 1 - (U_1 + U_2)$ but of course in this case, $U_2$ is dependent of $U_1$ (for example $U_2 > U_1$).

Do you know any trick that allows me to do it properly?

Comment: Hint:  Compare $P(U_1 >\frac{1}{2})$ with $P(U_1 >\frac{1}{2} \vert U_2 > \frac{1}{2})$

Comment: How about doing your first idea, then shuffle the three numbers?

Comment: If $U_1+U_2+U_3=1$, the numbers are *not independent*. Rethink your problem.

Comment: Does it work to choose each of the three values independently within $[0, 1]$ and then scale them as necessary to get the correct sum?

Comment: @RobertShore: "scale them as necessary" ???

Comment: $\frac{U_n}{U_1+U_2+U_3}$.  I suspect this doesn't work because triples around $\frac 13$ are too likely, but I'm not certain that's the case.

Comment: I suggest that you review both the comment of Arthur and the first comment of user1020575.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the triangle in three dimensional space spanned by the vertices $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$. Every point on this triangle represents a solution to the equation $U_1 + U_2 + U_3 = 1$. We map this triangle by to a right isosceles triangle in the plane spanned by $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, then double this triangle to create a square. At first I thought this was area-preserving, but I realized it's not quite, so we need to do a small adjustment. First you map it it to an equilateral triangle in the plane. It's side length will not be $1$, but $\sqrt{2}$ because the distance between any two of the three aforementioned vertices is $\sqrt{2}$. Then we can apply a shear matrix which maps this now-correctly-scaled equilateral triangle to a right triangle, which we can then double.

We pick a point in the square. If it's in the lower left portion, do the inverse of the area preserving map to determine your point. If it's in the upper right portion of the square, first reflect it over the line $y = 1- x$ to get it into the lower portion and then do the map.

Since the only part of the square that's overcounted is a line, which has area $0$, this process preserves probability and tells you how to go from picking a point uniformly in a square and turns it into such a probability as you desire.

Comment: I do not understand how can you obtain three independant uniform random variables  with the restriction proposed with that idea. Also, if you pick a random point in the square, wouldn't you get an inequality in the restrction instead of an equality?

Comment: You've misunderstood the construction. The triangle in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be identified with the set of numbers between $0$ and $1$ which add to $1$. Then I do some geometry to identify it with a triangle it is easy to sample randomly from.

Comment: Oh, you are right, still how do you obtain three uniform variables from there?

Comment: You don't, because there are only two independent variables. This is what I do. I select two variables independently and this determines the third, via linear algebra.

Comment: Then, how is the construction related to the question?

Comment: Well the question asks for something nonsensical. You can't ask for three independent things that have a dependence. Instead I am sampling from a cleverly selected space so that two of the variables are chosen independently at random and the result is that $U_1, U_2, U_3$ would appear to be selected uniformly at random if you say, ran a simulation with many samplings.

Comment: Okay, thanks you